# How to Initialize a sorted array in one line instead of creating the array and then sorting it

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In Java, I have an array of objects called `Pin` that I wish to have sorted. Currently, it takes three lines of code to return a sorted array of map objects like this:

```
Pin[] plist = PinList.values().toArray(new Pin[PinList.size()]);
Arrays.sort(plist,Pin.PinComp);//This is done to sort the pins
return plist;
```

Here, it grabs all of the Pins into a Pin Array, sorts the Array, and then returns the sorted array.I wish to shrink this to ONE statement of code, so that I can `return` in one line a new Pin Array that has been sorted.

Is it possible to create a sorted array, instead of creating an array and then sorting it?

Comment: Why on earth are you trying so hard to go out of your way to cram code into 1 single line? What you have seems logical and readable.

Comment: *"Is it possible to create a sorted array, instead of creating an array and then sorting it?"* No. Even the [stream solution given by shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446156/5221149) will internally create an array first, then sort it. You might not be doing it explicitly, but it still happens.

Comment: *"I wish to shrink this to ONE line of code"* Then put the 3 *statements* on the same *line*. I don't recommend it, but it would work.

Comment: I just feel that it's strange that instead of applying a command to sort the array, you must utilize a void method to change the array itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use streams:

```
return PinList.values()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Pin.PinComp)
        .toArray(Pin[]::new);
```

Comment: You could've put them on the same line for his benefit ;)